# Windows phone project run tests

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-8

I am using [WPToolkitTestFX](https://nuget.org/packages/WPToolkitTestFx) in Windows Phone 8 project. So I am running tests 
with special page, where in constructor I got:

```
this.Content = UnitTestSystem.CreateTestPage();
```

But if I want to run application, I need to change *Navigation Page* in WMAppManifest.xml. It is not good, because I often forgetting to change it back and pushing that WMAppManifest to source control system.

Is it possible to create **difference run configuration** for WP8 project? One for application, another for tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your unit tests in a different project with its own WMAppManifest.

Comment: Hm, and connect main project by reference?